# s3: what is the 'key' parameter of the s3.put_object() method?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-s3, boto

I am using [Boto](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) to upload artefacts to an s3 bucket, but don't know what the `Key` parameter of the `put_object()` method is:

```
client.put_object(
     Body=open(artefact, 'rb'),
     Bucket=bucket,
     Key=bucket_key
)
```

What gives?

Comment: `Key` is the object name inside S3. Bare in mind that s3 doesn't call it "file name" for a reason, because s3 doesn't support folder separation.  Indeed, you can create a key with forward and backward slash as part of the name.

Answer (score 12):

In Amazon S3, the `key` is the object name, or file name if your objects are files. The `key` is listed in the results when retrieving the contents of the bucket, and you retrieve the contents of the object by specifying the object's `key`.

Keys in Amazon S3 must be unique.

If an object in the bucket already exists using the `key` value you're specifying for your `PutObject` command, then the old object will be replaced with your new object. Essentially, it's overwriting it.